# Spring Data Cassandra and PreparedStatementCache

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I don't understand how to achieve very simple goal with Spring Data Cassandra.

I want to execute an "INSERT" statement multiple times with different parameter values. I don't have mapped domain class at the moment, so I use `CqlOperations` interface provided by Spring Data.

When I just use `execute(String cql, Object... args)`, Cassandra driver complains about "Re-preparing already prepared query is generally an anti-pattern and will likely affect performance. Consider preparing the statement only once". Because Spring Data uses `SimplePreparedStatementCreator`. But I don't see any way to tell Spring Data to use `CachedPreparedStatementCreator` instead. All I see is `execute(PreparedStatementCreator psc)` method which does not allow me to provide parameters values.

So, is there any way to either tell Spring Data to use proper statement cache or to achieve something similar to `execute(PreparedStatementCreator, Object...)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`CqlTemplate` exposes callback and customization hooks that allow for tailoring some of its functionality to the needs of your application.

`CqlTemplate` does intentionally come without caching as caching leads to time vs. space considerations. Spring Data Cassandra cannot make decisions as we cannot assume what applications typically require.

Spring Data Cassandra's package `core.cql.support` ships with support for `CachedPreparedStatementCreator` and a `PreparedStatementCache` that you can use for that purpose.

Subclass `CqlTemplate` and override its `newPreparedStatementCreator(…)` method to specify which `PreparedStatementCreator` to use. The following example shows an example for a cache with infinite retention:

```
public class MyCachedCqlTemplate extends CqlTemplate {

    PreparedStatementCache cache = MapPreparedStatementCache.create();

    @Override
    protected PreparedStatementCreator newPreparedStatementCreator(String cql) {
        return CachedPreparedStatementCreator.of(cache, cql);
    }

}
```

Comment: Cassandra driver 4.0+ doesn't log the warning as it says - 
`the session has a built-in cache, it’s OK to prepare the same string twice.`

https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.7/manual/core/statements/prepared/